# Create a build file to run the project

Tags: ant, build, batch-file

I have been given the following requirements.

1. Create a build file with ANT build that creates a .jar from the source file (Source being in ***D:\Root\Products\Application\Files*** )
2. Create a bat file to run the .jar saved in a different location(say in 
   ***D:\Root\Products\Application\ReleaseBuild***)

Where should I start with? I am new to build files and no idea how to begin with. And am a bit confused with the build tutorials.

Please someone suggest a way to begin with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The official Ant manual is by far the best place to start. If you have concrete questions, we would be happy to help. http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

Comment: Seriously? You really need do some research. There is tonnes of information on ANT out there.

Comment: There is a way to export a ANT script from eclipse. Haven't tried it though.. Please try and report. And yes, please do a little more research.

Comment: It is better to look for Ant Manual to start... Document is well written and quite informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. start with an ant-task that compiles the code to a temp directory (ant-task: `javac`)
2. package those files to a jar (ant-task `jar`) - see, step 1 is essential, because `jar` does only bundle the files, but does not compile the sources for you
3. create the bat-script using the ant-task `echo`